# What is the best way to compare multiple strings in C?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I'm trying to find the best way to compare multiple strings in C.
Currently, I'm using `strcmp();` function, but it's turning out to be too many `if`
statements. I was also using ternary operator but unfortunately for me, it doesn't help.
Is there any better solution?
Here is example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char command[] = "First Second Third";
    char * del = " ";
    char * token;
    char * strings[3];
    int n = 0;
    token = strtok(command, del);

    while (token != NULL){

        strings[n] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, del);
        n++;
    }
    // Now, strings[0] = "First", strings[1] = "Second", and strings[2] = "Third"

    // Only examine strings[1] and strings[2] after we know strings[0] = "First".
    if (strcmp("First", strings[0]) == 0){
        //do something
        if (strcmp("Second", strings[1]) == 0){
            //do something
            if (strcmp("Third", strings[2]) == 0){
                //do something
                printf("CORRECT");
                //do something
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Please focus your question by showing code which demonstrates your actual problem or the specific case you want to optimise.

Comment: sometimes you just have to type a lot of code - dont fish for tricks that obscure what you are trying to do

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem - *why* do you want to match multiple strings?  What are you trying to accomplish *by* matching multiple strings?  What is the high-level description of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

OP's code has some problems

- `while (token != NULL)` has no limit to 3 loops.  Code may attempt `strings[3] = token;`

  ```
  // while (token != NULL){
  while (n < 3 && token != NULL){
  ```
- Code uses `strings[0]`, `strings[1]`, `strings[2]` without first insuring that many tokens were parsed.

  ```
  // strcmp("First", strings[0]) == 0
  (n > 0 && strcmp("First", strings[0]) == 0)
  ```
- Code  saves a pointer to the original string.  Once `strtok()` is call again, the prior token can be lost/changed.

---

The "best" way involves hashing the key and targets, yet that is a lot to explain here.

Alternative: With such a simple match needed as in OP's example, code could use `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan.

```
int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0;
sscanf(command, "First %n Second %n Third %n", &n1, &n2, &n3);

if (n1) {      // n1 is non-zero if scan matched "First"
    //do something
    if (n2) {  // n2 is non-zero if scan matched "First Second"
        //do something
        if (n3) {
            //do something
            printf("CORRECT");
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `if` statements should be using `strcmp()` instead of the posted `strtok()`.  Also, I think you are looking for something more like `if ... else if ... else if ...`, rather than nested `if's`.

Depending on the real program you're writing (vs. posted), you could also use a `switch()` based on the first character in the string to compare.  It amounts to a crude hashing function.  (you may want to learn more about hashing to adapt what you have to what you want).

---

EDIT:
Maybe this is what you're getting at:
.
.
.

```
    if (strcmp(strings[0], "cmdA") == 0)
        processCmdA(strings[1], strings[2]);
    else
    if (strcmp(strings[0], "cmdB") == 0)
        processCmdB(strings[1], strings[2]);
    else
    if (strcmp(strings[0], "cmdC") == 0)
        processCmdC(strings[1], strings[2]);
.
.
.
void processCmdA(char* optionA, char* inputFileName)
{
    if (strcmp(optionA, "parse") == 0)
        parseFile(inputFileName);
    else
    if (strcmp(optionA, "cksum") == 0)
        computeCheckSum(inputFileName);
    else
.
.
.
}

void parseFile(char* inputFileName)
{
    // do parse stuff
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake with strtok function in `if` statements. I edited the post.
What I want to do is check if the command is correct. The parts of it can vary for example `char command[] = "First Second Third";` or `char command[] = "foo bar";`